# Extending function analytically

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to understand why the following is true: Suppose you have a complex holomorphic function such that $f(0)=0$, $0<|f'(0)|=\lambda<1$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that the sequence $\phi_n(z)=\frac{f^n(z)}{\lambda^n}$ ($f^n = f\circ\dots\circ f$) converges uniformly to an analytic function $\phi$ in the disk $\mathbb{D}(0,r)$. The proof of that I understand. My problem is with the following: If $A=\{z|f^n(z)\rightarrow0\}$, then we can extend $\phi$ to $A$ by setting $\phi(z)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f^n(z)}{\lambda^n}$. Although I see the functions must converge pointwise in $A$ since for each $z\in A$, $f^n (z)\in \mathbb{D}(0,r)$ for $n$ sufficiently large (thus the sequence is Cauchy), I don't see why $\phi$ would be analytic in $A$, since we can only guarantee uniform convergence in the disk... Is there another way to argument that this extension is analytic?

Comment: What is $f^n$? Is it the $n$-fold composition, the $n$th power of $f$, or the $n$th derivative?

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry, it's the $n$-fold composition

Comment: In that case, consider the set $A_n:= \{z | f^n(z) \in \mathbb{D}(0,r)\}$. On $A_n$ you have uniform convergence and you can prove that $\phi|_{A_n}$ is analytic. Conclude by using that $\cup A_n = A$.

Comment: Ah, I see now, thank you

Comment: @WillieWong But, Does uniform convengerce in every $A_n$ implies in uniform convergence in their union? By looking at the cauchy condition, given an epsilon, it seems that for the union I might need to take arbitrarly large values of $n$, which wouldn't work...
Here's a counter-example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473599/uniform-convergence-over-a-countable-union-of-sets

Comment: You don't need uniform convergence on their union. What you use is that every $A_n$ is open, and every $z\in A$ is in some $A_n$. So there is an open neighborhood of every $z$ on which the function $\phi(x)$, which you have already successfully defined as the pointwise limit, is a holomorphic function.